# jupyter notebook kernel tab add same environment twice

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, environment

[image: conda environment shown at front page (File tab)]

[image: conda environment shown at Conda tab]

Python [conda env:python3.7_test] and python 3.7_test is the same environment but it is registered twice in a different name.

Currently, to manage conda environment, I’m using nb_conda packages. It seems sometimes it automatically add a newly generated condo environment as Python [env_name], but sometimes it does not appear when I create a new Conda environment. Even I checked the Conda tab contains the newly created conda environment, python3.7_test env didn’t appear in the env tab on front page (File tab).

So I followed another guide to add kernel which is:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=python3.7_test
```

After that, Python [conda env:python3.7_test] and python 3.7_test appeared on the tab at the same time.

How can I manage conda environment well? Does conda environment automatically add on Jupyter kernel if I use nb_conda? How long should I wait and does nb_conda needs an extra process to add a new kernel?

Comment: Yes, `nb_conda` depends on `nb_conda_kernels` which provides automatic identification of environments with valid kernel packages installed (e.g., `ipykernel`). This makes it unnecessary to register the kernel at a user level. To delete a user-level registration, locate the user-level folder that stores registered kernels and delete the subfolder corresponding to this registration.

Comment: @fenneccat Did you get any solution? apart from deleting the subfolder?
I think you should use jupyter kernelspec remove python3.7_test command to delete that kernel.